# Go through a list of files in a directory and tabulate contents of var skipping over file if error occurs

Tags: stata

I'm trying to open all of the .dta files found in my directory, tabulate the year variable to check if the data provider sent me all of the years I requested, and locate the files that don't contain the year variable for closer examination. So far I've tried this:

```
local files: dir "$new" files "*dta"

foreach file in `files' {
    local file: subinstr local file ".dta" "" 
    use "$new\\`file'", clear
        if acadyr in `files' {
            di "`file'"
            tab acadyr, m
            di " "
            }
        else if _rc==111 {
            di "YEAR VAR NOT IN: `file'"
            ds
            di " "
        }
    }
```

I get `error not found`. I can avoid using `if else` by using `capture` but then nothing gets tabulated. Is there a way to create a condition where I do x if an error occurs but continue if it is not found? In python this could be done using `try` and `except` but I don't know how to do this in Stata, which is what I have to use for this project.

Comment: `if error 111` looks itself to be an error for `if _rc == 111` but (a) why check for that in particular? (b) why would you display a message that a variable hasn't been found before you have even checked for it?

Comment: You're right. Let me edit above to be more clear what my intention is.

Comment: `if acadyr in \`files'` doesn't look like anything legal.  `acadyr` isn't even defined in any code you show us.

Comment: Again, why 111?

Comment: I'm trying to check if the variable `acadyr` exists in the data set, if it does, tabulate it, if it doesn't use the 111 error to let me know that the variable doesn't exist and then list out the variables so I can look through them quickly. I found an answer on statalist that I've posted below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help. Some minor details:

Work in the directory of interest.

Eliding the `.dta` suffix has no obvious point.

```
cd $new
local files: dir . files "*dta"

foreach file of local files {
    use "`file'", clear
    di "`file'" 
    capture confirm variable acadyr 
    if _rc display "acadyr not found" 
    else tab acadyr, m
    di 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a [statalist](http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2009-03/msg00586.html) question that answered my question. I'll post my answer to clear up any confusion and if anyone else runs across this problem.

```
local files: dir "$new" files "*dta"

foreach file in `files' {
    use "$new\\`file'", clear
    capture confirm variable acadyr
        if !_rc {
            di "`file'"
            tab acadyr, m
            di " "
            }
        else {  
            di "YEAR VAR NOT IN: `file'"
            ds
            di " "
        }
    }
```

Comment: Overlaps with mine (which has much the same result).

Comment: Yours is cleaner and more concise. I'll accept it as the correct answer.